# git push error [remote rejected] (internal error)

Tags: git

Recently I am facing one peculiar problem about git push.

While pushing branch or tag it is giving the following error:

```
[remote rejected] some refs cannot be pushed ..... (internal error)
```

Then I have tried by running "git gc" command. And then the push command was successful.

I have tried to find the root cause by googling, but nothing found.

Is there anyone have any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: We'll probably need to see the rest of the output from `git push` to be able to evaluate what is happening...

Answer (score 0):

You had some outdated refs for remote branches I suspect that you were tracking.  I have seen this before, by cleaning up your repo, it removed the references that were dangling.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

So what could be the possible way to prevent this kind of error?
    -- Need to run "git gc" before executing git push command each time??

Comment: no - this should not happen often - usually a git fetch will clean it up as well.